# How to change the color of the dropdown menu buttons in the mantine-react-table library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the mantine-react-table library. It has a drop-down list menu - this is column filtering. How can I change the color of the labels in this menu?
Here is an interesting menu.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTVNp.png)

Tried to do so, but doesn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS8VT.png)

Here is the object with the help of which I set up the table and styles are written right there, judging by the documentation.

```
export const TestTable = () => {

const columns = useMemo(
        () => [
              {
                accessorKey: 'date', 
                header: 'Дата и время'
              },
              {
                accessorKey: 'message',
                header: 'Сообщение',
              }
        ],
        [],
      );

    const table = useMantineReactTable({
            columns,
            data,
            localization: MRT_Localization_RU,
            enablePagination: true,
            enableTopToolbar: false,
            mantineTableHeadCellProps: {sx: {
                '& .mantine-TableHeadCell-Content': {
                    color: '#004E8F',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                },
            }},
            mantineTableBodyCellProps: {sx: {color: '#004E8F', 
textAlign: 'left'}},
            
            mantineColumnActionsButtonProps: {sx: {
                '& .mantine-Menu-itemLabel': {
                    color: 'red',
                    fontSize: '1.3em'
                }
            }},
          });
    
        return <MantineReactTable table={table}/>;
```

I will be glad for any help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. We can't really help you without being provided some code in order to find the issue.  If you would, please provide some code using the ``` (3 backtics)